# player controller jitters unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when I jump up to an object that is a cube I reach the step offset and it jitters for a little bit before falling to the ground again. I can remove the step offset altogether but that's not what I want as my game is baste around parkour. when I was making this I was following a  Brackeys tutorial on YouTube. [Brackeys tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc)  can anyone help me out? [,first person object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH03B.png)   [, the object causing most problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoXU3.png)[, objects in scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goWCS.png)

```
using System.collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class keymovement : MonoBehaviour
{
public CharacterController controller;


public float speed = 12f;
public float gravity = -10f;

public Transform groundcheck;
public float groundDistance = 0.5f;
public LayerMask groundMask;

public float jumpheight = 3f;

Vector3 velocity; 
bool isgrounded;


void Update()
{
    isgrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundcheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

   

    if (isgrounded && velocity.y < 0)

    {
        velocity.y = -2;
  }

    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
    
    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetButton("jump") && isgrounded)
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpheight * -2f * gravity);
    }

    velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

      
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I have not added a Rigidbody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the Character controller is fighting with the velocity of the movement script because of how it checks for slopes and steps.

An easy fix is to set the controller's `slopeLimit` to `90f` while you are jumping:

```
void Update()
{
    isgrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundcheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

    if (isgrounded && velocity.y < 0)

    {
        velocity.y = -2;
        controller.slopeLimit = 45f;
    }
    
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && isgrounded)
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpheight * -2f * gravity);
        controller.slopeLimit = 90f;
    }

    velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: thanks so much this was really helpful and super effective.